# How to make an action listener Button for a Dice?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, dice

I am making a board game and I need to action a button which operates like a dice. In my frame, I have the throw dice button and next to it is a JLabel which would show the result of the dice. The problem is that I have a coding for dice in a different class and the button in another. I have an action class which would hold the code for action listener. How can I implement it? Below is my code.

### GameView Class:

```
 public void gui()
    {
        BorderLayout borderlayout = new BorderLayout();      
        
        //Creates the frame, set the visibility to true, sets the size and exit on close
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Games");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
        //Creates the Throw Dice button
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        p.add(new Button("Throw Dice"));
        p.add(new Label("Dice Draw")); //This is where I want the dice result to be shown when hit the button
        p.setBackground(new Color(156, 93, 82));
        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

### Dice Class:

```
public class Dice
{   
    //stores the dice result in the variable
    private int diceResult;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Dice
     */
    public Dice()
    {
        this.diceResult = diceResult;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random number between 1 and 5
     */
    public void randomGenerator ()
    {
        Random dice = new Random();
        diceResult = dice.nextInt(5)+1;
        System.out.println(diceResult);
    }
}
```

### Action Class:

```
public class Action
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple example like this i can recommend you to use advantages of anonymous class which implements `ActionListener` like this.

```
    BorderLayout borderlayout = new BorderLayout();      

    //Creates the frame, set the visibility to true, sets the size and exit on close
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Games");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    //Creates the Throw Dice button
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Dice dice = new Dice();
    Button button = new Button("Throw Dice");
    final Label label = new Label("Dice Draw");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dice.randomGenerator();
            label.setText(Integer.toString(dice.getDiceResult()));
        }
    });

    p.add(button);
    p.add(label); //This is where I want the dice result to be shown when hit the button
    p.setBackground(new Color(156, 93, 82));
    frame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Also you must add `getDiceResult` method to your `Dice` class.